# How to handle cgi form with Python requests

Tags: python, cgi, python-requests

I'm trying to use the requests module in Python to handle a cgi and can't work out what I've done wrong.

I've tried to use Google Dev Tools in Chrome to provide the right params and data but I've not quite fixed it.

The site I'm trying to get data from is: http://staffordshirebmd.org.uk/cgi/birthind.cgi

Here's my code

```
import requests 

headers = {"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate,sdch",
        "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "Cache-Control":"no-cache",
        "Connection":"keep-alive",
        "Content-Length":"124",
        "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "DNT":"1",
        "Host":"staffordshirebmd.org.uk",
        "Origin":"http://staffordshirebmd.org.uk",
        "Pragma":"no-cache",
        "Referer":"http://staffordshirebmd.org.uk/cgi/birthind.cgi?county=staffordshire",
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25"}

payload = {"county":"staffordshire",
          "lang": "",
          "year_date":"1837",
          "search_region":"All",
          "sort_by":"alpha",
          "csv_or_list":"screen",
          "letter":"A",
          "submit":"Display Indexes"}

f = requests.put(path, data=payload, headers=headers)

f.text
```

This provides the response:

```
u'<html>\n<body>\n<div>\n<p>\nThe Bookmark you have used to reach this page is not valid.\n</p>\n<p>\nPlease click <a href="http://staffordshirebmd.org.uk/">here</a> to return to the main page and reset your\nbookmark to that page.\n</p>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n\n'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't set the content-length and content type; those are handled for you just fine.

Comment: And are you certain the target takes PUT and not POST?

Comment: Thank you - I clearly wasn't concentrating. Put post and it works a treat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you used in your `Referrer` header has a form that uses `POST`, not `PUT`.

You rarely should hardcode the `Content-Length` header; do leave that up to `requests` to calculate for you and set. Different browsers can easily use subtly different content lengths, a script that only works with a fixed `Content-Length` would not last long.

Removing the `Content-Length` header and changing `.put()` to `.post()` gives me results, in any case.

Comment: Thanks for that. I appreciate the tip about Content-Length as well. Wasn't quite sure what to put in to get the results. :)